# Azure Functions Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, environment-variables, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions app that I'm testing locally but it doesn't appear to be picking up my `local.settings.json` configuration. I had to manually create the file since I've cloned this solution from my github repo (local.settings.json is set to ignore by default). I'm wondering if that's the issue and there's some way I'm not linking it to the project?

[image: Project Settings]

[image: local.settings.json]

[image: Calling code]

Comment: Hi Jack, may I know if there is any other json file in this project(which also has the "Values" key like the "local.settings.json") ?

Comment: Hi @HuryShen, this is the only one strangely. It gets built out to E:\GitHub\FunctionApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this problem? I am having the same issue. I have the file copied to debug folder. I just have one local.settings.json file, I didn't copy anything to manually to environment variables. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Since it is not the key. try to add json file to env on hand. Add a Startup class to your functionapp.

```
public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

**My guess is because this local.settings.json was created by yourself, so this file was not placed under the debug folder after compilation. Therefore, these values ​​are not entered into the environment variables.**

Based on this, I can give a solution, copy your local.settings.json file directly to the below folder, and then the problem should be solved.

[image]

**(There should be a local.settings.json file here, otherwise the environment variables cannot be entered.)**

Hope my inference is correct and hope this answer helps. :)

Comment: I've got it set to 'Copy if newer' so the local.settings.json file is in the debug folder as 'local.settings' with type 'JSON File'.

Comment: @JackOrr Already have local.settings.json? A null value means that the environment variable has not been read.

Comment: @JackOrr I have update. Try to add the json to env on hand.

Comment: The local.settings file I created myself is copied to E:\GitHub\RepoName\SolutionName\ProjectName\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1 during build process.

Comment: @JackOrr If it already exists, try to manually add to environment variables.

Comment: I'm not sure if that code will work for my project on runtime 2.1, it doesn't seem to trigger when I test. I put the configurationbuilder code right before I tried to access the environmentvariables and it didn't work either. I might just recreate the project and copy the files back in.

Comment: @JackOrr Ok i will follow up on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207614/discussion-between-jack-orr-and-bowmanzhu).

Answer (score 1):

make sure your local.settings.json is in the same place as the host.json at the project root and do a rebuild of your project after adding it also I get my azure function environment variables like so:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Issuer", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file build property `Copy to Output Directory` of the `local.settings.json` file is set to: `Copy if newer`. If not, change it.

[image]

The `local.settings.json` file needs to be in the binary folder at runtime. Else, these values ​​are not entered into the environment variables.

If you messed around with the file (like removed it from your project or copied it from another source and included it into your project) this file build property is set by default to `Do not copy` which causes the issue.